# Integrating using substitution

Tags: integration

I have the question:

[image]

Here is my attempt is this correct ?

[image]

Comment: Yes it is correct!  Just carry through the constant $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

However you lost your constant of integration somewhere in the middle.